# VS Code Suddenly Unusable, unbound breakpoints, flashing chrome Sources Tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been working on a VUE.js project for about 6 months. I have been able to run the project in VSCode using F5 "Start Debugging". It no longer works and I can't figure out why. Now, when I press F5 to start debugging, chrome opens and then just spins for a very long time. If I open the developer tools, it is stuck on the Sources tab and appears to be loading or parsing a large number of files. After a very long time, it seems to finish and  my project is rendered in Chrome. However, none of the breakpoint I had set will work. They change form the little red circle to an empty circle that says "unbound breakpoint" when I hover over it.

I've seen a few other issues that seem to be related to "unbound breakpoints" but they either did not seem to contain a solution or the stated solution did not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated. Please help...

Thanks,

Notes:
Vue.js Dev Tools Chrome Extension is installed
VS Code has Debugger for Chrome and Vetur extensions but I get the same issue when I disable them.
I can't say for certain, but maybe the problem started last time I updated, current versions;
Electron: 12.0.13
VSCode: 1.58.2
Node.js 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0

My launch.json...

```
{

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Additional information: Only the .vue files seem to be affected. I can put breakpoints in main.js and in my vuex modules and they work as expected. It's only the breakpoints I set inside .vue files that change from red to "empty circle" when the debugger is launched with F5.

Comment: If it just randomly started happening without anything else changing, then it might be related to VSCode's cache, which can get corrupted rarely.  You could try clearing it.  I can't vouch for this site but I found this: https://www.programmersought.com/article/59887862628/

Comment: More Info: I enabled trace in launch.json and examined the trace file. I think the problem is related to the fact that invalid paths are getting generated relating to webpack and source maps. Example invalid path: file:///D:/Users/myuser/dev/source/repos/Appx_Vue/appx-vue/node_modules/webpack/hot/webpack:/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js".